# Calculating time between lines - How to use an extra timestamp for the last line

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having trouble calculating time between lines.
I would like to calculate how much time an user spent at the station on a specific day.
The first problem is the one line offset, result is shown in the line below.
The second problem is how can I use the end of shift time for the last user row.

```
 CREATE TABLE adata (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    station_id INT NOT NULL,
    shift_stop TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    shift_date DATE NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    shift_start TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

insert into adata (id,user_id,station_id,shift_stop,shift_date,created_at, shift_start) values 
(1, 1, 1, '2022-01-01 15:00:00', '2022-01-01','2022-01-01 10:00:00'),
(2, 2, 1, '2022-01-01 15:00:00', '2022-01-01','2022-01-01 10:01:00','2022-01-01 10:00:00'),
(3, 1, 2, '2022-01-01 15:00:00', '2022-01-01','2022-01-01 11:00:00','2022-01-01 10:00:00'),
(4, 2, 2, '2022-01-01 15:00:00', '2022-01-01','2022-01-01 12:00:00','2022-01-01 10:00:00'),
(5, 2, 3, '2022-01-01 15:00:00', '2022-01-01','2022-01-01 12:30:00','2022-01-01 10:00:00');

select 
        t.user_id, 
        t.shift_stop,
        t.created_at, 
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (lag(t.created_at) over (partition by t.user_id order by t.created_at ) - t.created_at )) as time,        t.station_id, 
        t.id
    FROM adata t 
    where DATE(t.shift_date) = '2022-01-01'
```

Exmaple: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a8979/1

Comment: Please also include the expected result in the question.

Comment: What do you mean `How to use an extra timestamp for the last line` could you give us an example?

Comment: @D-Shih I mean shift_stop for the last line

Comment: can you your expected output

Comment: There is a column `shift_stop` in your table do you mean want to select it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE` to use `shift_stop` value and `LEAD` to get the time a user spent at a station.

```
SELECT
    *,
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (COALESCE(LEAD(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, shift_date ORDER BY created_at), shift_stop) - created_at)) AS time
FROM adata    
WHERE DATE(shift_date) = '2022-01-01'
ORDER BY user_id, id
```

Or you can provide a default value for `LEAD` function

```
SELECT
    *,
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (LEAD(created_at, 1, shift_stop) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, shift_date ORDER BY created_at) - created_at)) AS time
FROM adata    
WHERE DATE(shift_date) = '2022-01-01'
ORDER BY user_id, id
```

Both queries return the same results:

| id | user_id | station_id | shift_stop | shift_date | created_at | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 15:00:00 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 10:00:00 | 3600.000000 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 2022-01-01 15:00:00 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 11:00:00 | 14400.000000 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2022-01-01 15:00:00 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 10:01:00 | 7140.000000 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 2022-01-01 15:00:00 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | 1800.000000 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 2022-01-01 15:00:00 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 12:30:00 | 9000.000000 |

You can check a working demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=32d136535504da1554e9af2e226645c7)

Comment: You can also provide a default value for the `lag()` function: `lag(created_at, 1, shift_stop)`